# ConTeXt: \someline breaks kerning rules of font

Tags: context, kerning

I found out that \someline (for getting a reference to the line number) breaks the kerning of the font.

For example, I want to adjust the kerning between the characters "," and "1", and I do this by adding a kerning rule to my font in fontforge. In this example, I added a lot of space, for the sake of better visibility.

Now, if I write twice a line containing both characters in sequence, and in the second line insert a `\someline` command between these characters

```
\startluacode
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "ktest",
    type = "kern",
    data = { [","] = { ["1"] = 500 } }
  }
\stopluacode

\definefontfeature
  [default]
  [default]
  [ktest=yes]

\setupbodyfont[modern]

\starttext

p.1,123\par
p.1,\someline[x]123\par

\stoptext
```

then I get the following result:

[image: example]

The space within the first line is the kerning. In the second line, obviously, this is prevented by the insertion of `\someline`. To me it seems as if this command produced some token of its own, so the "," and the "1" are not contiguous any more.

So how can I get a reference to the line number at a certain position and at the same time adjust the kerning of the characters at that position?

I may need to add that actually the problem is more complex, and just putting the `\someline` to another position is not an option.

Comment: Which font are you using? It works fine with Latin Modern

Comment: I bet that `\someline` inserts a whatsit which inhibits kerning.

Comment: Please always post MWEs. I've added one for you.

Answer (score 2):

As I've already suspected, there are additional nodes inserted by `\someline` in between `,` and `1`. We can visualize it using:

```
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\tracingoutput=1
\tracingonline=1
\normalshipout\vbox{
  p.1,\someline[x]123\par
}
\tracingoutput=0
\tracingonline=0
```

The logfile will then contain

```
\vbox(7.98761+2.32672)x426.78743, direction TLT
.\hbox(7.98761+2.32672)x426.78743, glue set 389.46393fil, direction TLT
..\localpar
...\localinterlinepenalty=0
...\localbrokenpenalty=0
...\localleftbox=null
...\localrightbox=null
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
..<1: lmroman10-regular @ 12.0pt> p
..<1: lmroman10-regular @ 12.0pt> .
..<1: lmroman10-regular @ 12.0pt> 1
..<1: lmroman10-regular @ 12.0pt> ,
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
...\latelua0 <function reference 790>
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
...\latelua0 <function reference 791>
..<1: lmroman10-regular @ 12.0pt> 1
..<1: lmroman10-regular @ 12.0pt> 2
..<1: lmroman10-regular @ 12.0pt> 3
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```